# Undefined index: ELEMENT Laravel dusk

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab, laravel-dusk

We have a laravel project that we test using dusk browsertests.

The tests were working fine until yesterday.

now we get a Undefined index: ELEMENT error on every test.

We have tried running the CI CD Pipline again and clearing cache.

1) Tests\Browser\ArtikelBearbeitenTest::testArtikelBearbeiten_GreenPath
ErrorException: Undefined index: ELEMENT

> /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:190
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/ElementResolver.php:310
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/ElementResolver.php:84
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/InteractsWithElements.php:142
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/tests/Browser/Pages/LoginPage.php:82
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:479
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/tests/Browser/F_001/ArtikelBearbeitenTest.php:60
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:67
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/tests/Browser/F_001/ArtikelBearbeitenTest.php:81

2) Tests\Browser\ArtikelErfassenTest::testArtikelErfassenGreenPath
ErrorException: Undefined index: ELEMENT

> /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:190
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/ElementResolver.php:310
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/ElementResolver.php:84
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/InteractsWithElements.php:142
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/tests/Browser/Pages/LoginPage.php:82
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:479
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/tests/Browser/F_001/ArtikelErfassenTest.php:28
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:67
>   /builds/mike.noethiger/ip12-18vt_webshop_2/build/app/tests/Browser/F_001/ArtikelErfassenTest.php:36

Comment: Has something changed in the view where you were asserting before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Docker hosted Selenium image that is locked to the latest version then it looks like a recent deployment may have broken some functionality.

Try using an older version (https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome-debug/tags). We've had a similar problem in our CI but changing to the `3.141.59-oxygen` tag seems to have fixed it.